# Integral involving l1-norm

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, indefinite-integrals, change-of-variable

I am trying to figure out how to evaluate an integral of the following form. Assume that $\textbf{x}$ is a $P \times 1$ vector, where $||.||_1$ reprents the l-1 norm, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^P |x_{j}|$.

The simplest version to evaluate is this first integral as you can just re-write the l1-norm and integrate directly.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(- ||\textbf{x}||_1) d\textbf{x} = 2^P$$

The trickier part is I'm now trying to figure out how to do this when I left multiply $\textbf{x}$ by some matrix $\textbf{A}$, i.e:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(- ||\textbf{A}\textbf{x}||_1) d\textbf{x} = ?$$

My thought was to do some change of variables on the integral, i.e. $\textbf{y} = \textbf{A} \textbf{x}$, but as $\textbf{A}$ isn't necessarily square, I wasn't really sure how to do this in a general case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do, [thin QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $A$. When $R_1$ is not invertible the integral diverges. When $R_1$ is invertible, do your changes of variable.

Comment: Thanks! Could you say more about how this helps? It seems like when I do the QR decomposition, I'm left with the l1 norm of Q times the transformed matrix and thus I still have the same problem. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Comment: Also I am still confused about how to do the change of variables with $R_1$?

Comment: Assume that $R_1$ is invertible, otherwise the integral diverges. Then we can do the change of variable $y=R_1x$. The integral becomes $|R_1|^{-1}\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp(-\|Q\cdot Id\cdot y\|)dy$, where $Id$ is the identity followed by a few extra zero rows. If $q_1,...,q_n$ are the first $n$ columns of $Q$, then the integral is the same as $|R_1|^{-1}\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp(-\|y_1q_1+...+y_nq_P\|)dy$, where $q_1,...,q_P$ are orthogonal vectors (of dimension $m>P$).

Comment: What remains is a combinatorial thing. The space $\mathbb{R}^n$ gets partitioned into the sectors on which each component of $y_1q_1+...+y_nq_n$ has constant sign. Each sector is a cone limited by a bunch of hyperplanes passing through the origin. On each sector the integrand is of the form $e^{v\cdot y}$ for some vector $v$ and $\cdot$ denoting the dot product this time.

Comment: [A picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3De%5E(-%7Cx-y%7C-%7Cx%2By%7C-%7Cx%7C)) for the case $n=2$, $q_1=(1,1,1)$ and $q_2=(-1,1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful; I wonder, however, if we can get an even simpler solution: Once we have $Q \cdot Id \cdot y$, why not perform a final change of variables to remove $Q$ and then eliminate the whole thing. So then we get that the answer is $|R_1|^{-1} \cdot 2^{m}$

Comment: The answer is not $|R_1|^{-1}\cdot 2^m$. For the example of vectors $q_1,q_2$ that I wrote above, [the result is $10/9$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+e%5E(-%7Cx-y%7C-%7Cx%2By%7C-%7Cx%7C)+from+x%3D-infty+to+x%3D%2Binfty+from+y%3D-infty+to+y%3D%2Binfty), instead of $2^2$. Notice that although I denoted it $Id$, that matrix is not the identity. It is the identity with extra zero rows at the bottom.

Comment: My hope is that there is someway to do another change of variables to eliminate the $Q$ matrix and thus have something that can be eliminated entirely. In the case of $R_1$ being invertible, I am wondering whether there is a closed-form solution to the integral.

Comment: Yes, there is a closed form, which you would obtain by doing what I said above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be dimension of our space (sorry, I change $P$ with $n$) and let $A$ be a $k \times n$ matrix ($k$ rows and $n$ columns). Let $k \leq n$. Write $A$ in the block form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
A_1 &A_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A_1$ consists of the first $k\times k$ elements and $A_2$ consists of the last $k\times (n-k)$ elements. Now form $n \times n$ matrix $B$ as the following
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 
A_1 &A_2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(here $1$ stands for the identity matrix).
This $B$ serves your desired change of variables. Note that if $k<n$ the integral diverges.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to think through this answer in the k > n case but I think it can't be true that if k < n the integral diverges. Consider the case where A = [1,0,0,0] and x is a 4 dimensional vector. A * x = x_1 and the integral evaluates to '2'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MGA in this case the integral becomes $\int e^{-|x_1|} dx_1 \dotsm dx_4 = \infty$. The case $k>n$ is lost in my answer, indeed. In this case we want to reduce $A$ to an upper triangular matrix (something with zero rows), as in the comment by nextpuzzle (note $\operatorname{rk} A \leq n$).

Comment: Thanks. Could you say more about where $B$ comes from? Why can't I flip the order of the identity matrix and 0 in the augmented matrix?